# How to make a website that uses fullpage.js go fullscreen on Safari for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm working on a [wordpress website](http://quentincarnaille.com/) that uses the [`fullpage.js` plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullpage/).

My main goal is to make it go fullscreen on iOS devices, latest versions are the main targets. By making it go fullscreen I mean getting rid of the ugly top and bottom bars, as you can see on this picture, [in landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y06JG.png) those bars take up more than 25% of the space.

I've tried  [this](//github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), but of course all browsers are compatible except safari iOS.

I've also tried all tips I found on [here](//www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen)  like including the meta "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You should include your code inside your question's body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apple devices in Safari, getting rid of the `anchors` option of fullPage.js will do the trick.

Not sure about other mobile phones or browsers, but it is well known browsers don't provide a way to deal with those bars and therefore there won't be much you can do about it.

Comment: By getting rid of the `anchors` you mean setting it to an empty array right? Thank you I'm going to try that!

Comment: Just remove the option from your initialization.

Comment: Because I'm using a wordpress plugin, this isn't as simple as that. For those in the same situation, `anchors` array is filled in the function `init_fullpage_params()` in the `wp-content/plugins/wp-fullpage/inc/fullpage/fullpage.php` file. Thanks a lot @Alvero, this hack seems to work quite well on iOS devices when viewed in landscape.